# Connect to MySQL container from Web Api .Net Core Container? How to get Ip Address?

Tags: c#, mysql, docker, docker-network

I know this is such a noob problem but I am having trouble understanding how to get  my .Net Core website to connect to my MySql container. So some background, both the MySql and the .Net core website are in their separate containers. I have already started the MySql container and setup the root account to work. I am using Entity Framework inside of .Net Core project.

I created the MySql container using this statement: 
`docker run --name mysql_container -d -p 3306:3306`

Below is the dockerfile that Visual Studio generated for me.

So what do I tell my .Net Core program to is the IP address of the MySql container if the IP can change?

Inside of .Net Core Program:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            var connection = $"Server={GetDBAddress()};Database=myDataBase;Uid=root;Pwd=root;";
            services.AddDbContext<ToDoContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(connection));
        }
```

If I write the GetDBAddress function what goes in there? I cannot simply return localhost because it's another docker container? As of right now I am trying to use localhost and I get connection refused. But I am able to connect to the MySql db using workbench.

Also I am not sure but can these two setups be combined into some file I think they're called docker-compose files maybe?

Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ToDoService/ToDoService.csproj", "ToDoService/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ToDoService/ToDoService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ToDoService"
RUN dotnet build "ToDoService.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ToDoService.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ToDoService.dll"]
```

Comment: Are the two containers running on the same machine? Are you using docker-compose? Because in the first case you can refer to localhost, but you have to expose the right ports in order to make the container reachable from the outside

Comment: The containers are running on the same machine with linux containers. The MySql container I just setup using this. `docker run --name mysql_container -d -p 3306:3306` Then I'll update the question with the dockerfile that visual studio created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've launched MySQL exposing the ports you should be able to reach it connecting from `localhost`, with the port `3306`.
Otherwise, as you suggested, there is the possibility to set up a `docker-compose file`. This file usually contains all the configuration your application needs to run. So, for example, a suitable configuration for your application (note: I'm assuming you're using MySQL 5.7 since you haven't specified one) could be:

```
version: '3.3'

services: # list of services composing your application
   db: # the service hosting your MySQL instance
     image: mysql:5.7 # the image and tag docker will pull from docker hub
     volumes: # this section allows you to configure persistence within multiple restarts
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always # if the db crash somehow, restart it
     environment: # env variables, you usually set this to override existing ones
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
       MYSQL_DATABASE: todoservice
       MYSQL_USER: root
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
   todoservice: # you application service
     build: ./ # this tells docker-compose to not pull from docker hub, but to build from the Dockerfile it will find in ./
     restart: always
     depends_on: # set a dependency between your service and the database: this means that your application will not run if the db service is not running, but it doesn't assure you that the dabase will be ready to accept incoming connection (so your application could crash untill the db initializes itself)
       - db

volumes:
    db_data: # this tells docker-compose to save your data in a generic docker volume. You can see existing volumes typing 'docker volume ls'
```

To launch and deploy your application, now you need to type in a terminal:
`docker-compose up`
This will bring up your deploy. Note that no ports are exposed here: only your service will be able to access the database from `db:3306` (you don't need to refer by IP, but you can reach other services using the service name).
For debug purposes, you can still open your db ports adding this line under `image`:

```
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
```

Note that this port has to be free (no other system services are using it), otherwise the entire deployment will fail.

Final note: since docker-compose will try to avoid to build your images every time you bring up the service, to force it to build a new one you have to append `--build` to the `docker-compose up` command.

To bring down your deploy just use `docker-compose down`. To delete all the persistent data related to your deploy (i.e. starting with a new db) append the `-v` flag at the end of the previous command.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am working on adding this into a docker compose file, I am running into some issues but I think I need Visual Studio to perform a clean on the docker compose it created before adding some of these bits.

Comment: To clean everything a docker-compose has created you should use something like `docker-compose down -v --rmi all` (I'm going by heart with this command) before editing the docker-compose that created the resources in the first place. To clean instead the images you're not actively using in your docker installation the command you're searching for is `docker image prune -a`. Use it carefully!

Comment: I am not sure what Visual Studio does but the 'Clean' command inside VS seems to do most of that.

Comment: I cannot help you here since I don't use Visual Studio. In any case, check if it has cleared everything with `docker ps -a`. If there aren't running instances of your application then you're fine, I think.

Comment: Alright I am just trying to make sure that everything is 'secure'. If my MySql container is running in 1 container and my Api in another I shouldn't have to expose port 3306 out to the host machine? So I am working on testing that

Comment: Well I have to say thank you so much for sticking around for this ride! I have gotten my database connection working so that my container can connect and my host machine cannot! I have setup my code to create the database if it needs to be, etc. Now I can work on developing my actual API! You are really amazing and thank you so much for sticking around for all this.

Comment: Glad to help. BTW yes, you don't have to expose your db port to the world, but only for development purposes.

On top of that, if you really want to make your deployment secure, consider [setting your environment variables in a separate file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option) so that you can publish your docker-compose but keep you DB credentials secure.

Have a great day, cheers!